# wowza aws instance creation through aws php sdk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, wowza, aws-php-sdk

I just want to create an instance using php aws sdk.
But my requirement is that wowza needs to be installed to that instance.
So is it possible that I give request to aws to create an instance and at the same time install wowza through code to that instance?